# Bind ObservableCollection count to wpf label and format the label

Tags: wpf, xaml, label

I have a label where I want to show the number of selected items in a list ( list items are selected from a grid ).  That all works well and the label displays the number.  What I want is to make the label display  "5 items selected".  Right now, I just get the number 5.  Here is the xaml:

```
<Label  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0" Name="lblSelectionSummary" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="557" FontFamily="Arial" >
        <Label.Content>
            <Binding Path="SelectedRows.Count" />
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
```

I'm close on this guy.

Answer (score 3):

you just need to specify the `StringFormat` in your binding

this should do

```
<Binding Path="SelectedRows.Count" StringFormat="{}{0} items selected"/>
```

above may not work for Label as it follows Content model , so you may need to use TextBlock instead

sample

```
<TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0" Name="lblSelectionSummary" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="557" FontFamily="Arial" >
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="SelectedRows.Count" 
                 StringFormat="{}{0} items selected"/>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

or

```
<TextBlock Height="23"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="7,2,0,0"
           Name="lblSelectionSummary"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Width="557"
           FontFamily="Arial"
           Text="{Binding SelectedRows.Count, StringFormat={}{0} items selected}" />
```

**Use string format with a Label**

StringFormat in binding works for string type properties, and since type of Content property of Label is object so StringFormat does not work

thanks to blindmeis for the hint

since a Label follows Content model it uses ContentStringFormat to format the value, below is an example to use the same

```
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedRows.Count}" 
       ContentStringFormat="{}{0} items selected" />
```

Comment: I think it should be `StringFormat="{}{0} items selected"`. Just `{0}` would make the compiler look for a markup exctension called 0.

Comment: I just tried StringFormat="{}{0} items selected, but the words items selected did not show up.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you, you may choose to accept this as an answer. happy coding :)